# How to get package/application name of a class in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am using `UsageStatsManager` to get application name, it worked well. However, I want to get more detail of a application. For example, my application has three activity, I want to get name of the activity when I am in the activity using bellow function. However, I tried to rename the activity name, but the bellow functions still return the application package and application name. How can I solve that?

```
public String getAppName() {
    String foregroundProcess = "";
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {                                           UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) getSystemService(USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<UsageStats> stats = mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000 * 1000, time);              // Sort the stats by the last time used
        if (stats != null) {
            SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>();
            for (UsageStats usageStats : stats) {
                mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
            }
            if (mySortedMap != null && !mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
                String topPackageName = mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName;
                foregroundProcess = topPackageName;
            }
        }
    } else {                                                                                  
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo foregroundTaskInfo = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0);
        foregroundProcess = foregroundTaskInfo.topActivity.getPackageName();
    }

    //Convert package name to application name
    final PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    ApplicationInfo ai;
    try {
        ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(foregroundProcess, 0);
    } catch (final PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        ai = null;
    }
    final String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");
    Log.d("Runing package",foregroundProcess);
    Log.d("Runing app",applicationName);
    return applicationName;
}
```

I tried to assign the name to the class in the **Manifest** file but it is still return application name

```
   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Hello">
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.camera.AndroidCamera"
        android:label="AndroidCamera"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();

Comment: @Thank David, but it still return the application package. I want to get packet name of AndroidCamera activity such as `com.example.camera.AndroidCamera`

Comment: "I want to get name of the activity when I am in the activity"  Why can't you use PACKAGE_NAME + AndroidCamera.class.getSimpleName();

Comment: @Michael: Your code return `Application` only

Comment: You mean the method `getAppName()` is in your activity? Then just calls `this.getClass().getCanonicalName()`

Comment: @TreyCai: It still return `android.app.Application`, similar with Michael answer. I want to get package name or application of a class. My application has three class. When the class is running, It will return the package name of the class, instead of the application

Comment: @user3051460 public String getAppName() { return this.getClass().getCanonicalName() }